# Magento 2 ordered product report

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, reports

```
Report -> Product -> Ordered
```

I want to add **new column Brand** (f_brand) in report **grid**.

I am unable to find any `Grid.php` or something like this file.

Can anyone help me on this? Which file I need to override and how can I add new column in this grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the columns of that report are created in the layout file [reports_report_product_sold_grid.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Reports/view/adminhtml/layout/reports_report_product_sold_grid.xml). You would need to add a file with this name in your own module (e.g. `Company/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout/reports_report_product_sold_grid.xml`) and add a new column block. Something like this

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.sku" as="sku">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SKU</argument>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">order_items_sku</argument>
        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
        <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-sku</argument>
        <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-sku</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

If you need custom functionality you could create a new Block that extends `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column`.

Comment: Good one :) ... Lets say I have added new column with index `brand_f` how can I populate data in it? Many thanks for your support

Comment: You'll need to populate the collection with data in that index. My guess is most likely you will create a plugin on `source/vendor/magento/module-reports/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Sold/Collection.php::addOrderedQty` function and add your column as a join to the select.

Comment: hi @rain2o, I have successfully populated the data, but i want to add custom filter for this new column ?